# TypeScript not accessing or importing node module

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

first, to say, I am new to Angular.

I am trying to use the crypto-js module to encrypt and decrypt a string passed to a Service. The service is injected to whoever uses it. My Problem is, apparently I can not Import a reference to this module.

My current set up is:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 9.7.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.3.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

The crypto-js package was installed by npm and the folder is properly located in the node_modules folder as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: Folder is located in node_modules]

My Service (It will not contain any sensitive information in the code in future, just for testing) looks like this:

```
import {Injectable, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core";
// will be used in future
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";

const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
// Todo generate password
const password = '1xap0957/ara=Xv9';

@Injectable()
export class Abc_tService implements OnDestroy {

  Enc(text) {
    // Encrypt
    var en = this.encrypt(text);
    console.log(en);
    console.log(this.decrypt(en));
  }

  private encrypt(text: string): string {

    return text;
  }

  private decrypt(text): string {

    return text;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {

  }
}
```

The Enc(text) Method is used for testing. Now my problem is, that I can't import or access the crypto-js module.

[image: Hovering shows me that the IDE does not have access already]

When I try to import it, I also can't access it. Now my imported reference seems to reference my own class:

[image: references own class]

My Goal is to use the crypto-js module in my service. What am I missing?

Comment: Install `@types/crypto-js`

Comment: ok, that was an easy one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Aluan Haddads comment on my question. The Solution simply was, I had to install the type. I did this using npm with the command:

```
npm install --save @types/crypto-js
```

Comment: I should also mention, that this service above implements OnDestroy, which would be a hook on ngOnDestroy in Angular. Since I played around with this being a service, the ngOnDestroy method will never be executed. Just a side note.